# Convert string representing object to javascript object

Tags: javascript, string, object

I'm currently using jqplot to display some charts and prepare javascript code with php.

On one of my chart, I use Ajax to get a new chart. For this, I get a json array with the list of values and chart option as a string like this :

This is the JSON I get :

```
{"idGraphe":"bar_chart_5","conditions":"[]","data":"[[[1,80423],[2,62634],[3,70625],[4,72187],[5,72739],[6,70078],[7,72751],[8,74300],[9,75550],[10,72482],[11,70971],[12,77579]],[[1,73386],[2,70068],[3,85018],[4,69761],[5,75317],[6,68240],[7,72487],[8,74716],[9,74340],[10,75012],[11,74800],[12,83105]]]","options":"{series : [{label : 'consommationtotale Pilote1' , yaxis : 'yaxis' },{label : 'consommationtotale Pilote2' , yaxis : 'yaxis' }] , seriesDefaults : {renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer , rendererOptions : {barWidth : null} } , cursor : {show : true , zoom : true, showTooltip : false}, highlighter : {showTooltip : true , tooltipAxes : 'both' , tooltipContentEditor : getPointInfo , show : true} , title : 'Bar chart', legend : {show : true , renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer}, axes : {xaxis:{ tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer , renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,pad : 0 , label : 'mois' , labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer}, yaxis:{ label : 'consommationtotale' , labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer }}}"}
```

And this is the part I have problem with :

```
"{series : [{label : 'consommationtotale Pilote1' , yaxis : 'yaxis' },{label : 'consommationtotale Pilote2' , yaxis : 'yaxis' }] , seriesDefaults : {renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer , rendererOptions : {barWidth : null} } , cursor : {show : true , zoom : true, showTooltip : false}, highlighter : {showTooltip : true , tooltipAxes : 'both' , tooltipContentEditor : getPointInfo , show : true} , title : 'Bar chart', legend : {show : true , renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer}, axes : {xaxis:{ tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer , renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,pad : 0 , label : 'mois' , labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer}, yaxis:{ label : 'consommationtotale' , labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer }}}"
```

My problem is that in order to draw the chart with proper options, I need to pass this as a javascript object. And that what I can't figure how to do to convert my string to the corresponding javascript object.

I tried to cast it as an object but without success, I've not so much ex^periences with javascript.

Does anyone would have a solution or a tip ?

Thanks

Comment: This is not JSON. If it was JSON, you could parse it with `JSON.parse`. I recommend to fix your server process to create proper JSON.

Comment: This should do it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I've updated my question. The JSON I get is correct and I've no problem to access its properties. The only problem I've is that I get the options as a string and I've to convert it as an object.

Comment: This is really unsafe and should not be done. I thus [refuse](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.ASP) to [give](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/12k71sw7(v=vs.94).aspx) you the function that would help here :)

Comment: The answer is still the same: Create a proper JSON object, i.e. where the value of `"options"` is not a string but an object.

Comment: I aggree that its better to create a proper json object than a string but I could manage to do it because of lines like : 'tickRenderer':$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer, php dont accept it and so I cant have my full object to apply json_encode on it. Maybe there is a solution but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Some modern browsers have support for parsing JSON into a native object:

```
var x = "{series : [{label : 'consommationtotale Pilote1' , yaxis : 'yaxis' },{label : 'consommationtotale Pilote2' , yaxis : 'yaxis' }] , seriesDefaults : {renderer : $.jqplot.BarRenderer , rendererOptions : {barWidth : null} } , cursor : {show : true , zoom : true, showTooltip : false}, highlighter : {showTooltip : true , tooltipAxes : 'both' , tooltipContentEditor : getPointInfo , show : true} , title : 'Bar chart', legend : {show : true , renderer: $.jqplot.EnhancedLegendRenderer}, axes : {xaxis:{ tickRenderer:$.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer , renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,pad : 0 , label : 'mois' , labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer}, yaxis:{ label : 'consommationtotale' , labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer }}}";
var result = JSON.parse(x);
```

For the browsers that don't support it, you can download json2.js from json.org for safe parsing of a JSON object.